# Combined updates in Ruby Activerecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Is there a better way to do multiple updates in Ruby Activerecord (not Rails) as to what I do here ? I don't want to loop over all the records and work with if's or case's.

```
# reset all color fields to null
Signal.where.not(color: nil).update_all("color = null")
# set color field based on status
Signal.where(status: CONFIG.status.step3).update_all("color = 'o'")
Signal.where(status: CONFIG.status.step4).update_all("color = 'r'")
Signal.where(status: CONFIG.status.manual).update_all("color = 'y'")
```

Comment: I came from worse but the number of colors could rise and repetitions in code aren't nice, also if there was a way to do everything in one update (and keep being readable) it would execute faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you could do it more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and use hash style for arguments instead string in `update_all`:

```
# reset all color fields to null
Signal.where.not(color: nil).update_all(color: nil)
# set color field based on status
color_dependencies = {
  CONFIG.status.step3 => 'o', 
  CONFIG.status.step4 => 'r', 
  CONFIG.status.manual => 'y'
}

color_dependencies.each do |status, color| 
  Signal.where(status: status).update_all(color: color) 
end
```

Comment: more DRY yes, but you can't use a constant for color_dependencies, otherwise error 'dynamic constant assignment', the updates are still one after the other though

Comment: Also worth noting that this would be a great candidate for wrapping in `Signal.transaction do ... end` to make sure this happens in one shot, not stalling out half-way through for whatever reason or tripping up over other instances of the same code.

Comment: @peter, you're right. I replaced it by variable, so `color_dependencies` can be modified later in code if needed.

Comment: a pity the first reset can't be added in the hash and not verything is done in one sweep. for the moment I'm gonna accept your answer since it gives at least part of the sollution

Comment: @peter you can also wrap it in Signal.transaction like @tadman said (more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). In this case it will be faster than doing separated `update_all` queries because all requests will be done in single database `BEGIN....COMMIT` block instead of multiple. And this is more safely because will be rolled back if something goes wrong. Here is more aboout that in mysql: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-transactions.htm

Comment: @boris&tadman: I read about that but it wasn't clear to me what the speed benefit would be, and the safety isn't an issue here, i'll do a few benchmarks, thanks for the update